# disengage mousewheel.js at end of bxslider vertical slide navigation

Tags: jquery, bxslider, mousewheel

**Background:** I'm using the bx slider.  I'm scrolling fullscreen sliders vertically with a dot navigation floated right.  I  added mouse navigation on the slides to scroll vertically up and down with the mouse/trackpad using mousewheel.js.  The slides scroll up and down fine, but at the end of the last slide, scrolling down does nothing, as it's the last slide.  I'm trying to figure out a way to scroll down to the footer if the last slide is exposed.

I thought of turning mousewheel.js if we're on the last slide, but the problem with that is that the user wouldn't be able to slide up to the previous slide when on the last slide, with would be bad for UX.

The site's on local right now, but here's all my code (aside from the bxslider, of course).

**Slide HTML**

```
<div id="slider-home" class="sabreSlider">
    <ul id="bxslider" class="bxslider">
      <li class="sabre" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sabretooth1.jpg');"></li>
      <li class="sabre" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sabretooth2.jpg');"></li>
      <li class="sabre" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sabretooth3.jpg');"></li>
      <li class="sabre sabreLast" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sabretooth4.jpg');"></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- #slider-home > end -->
```

**jQuery**

```
(function(window, $) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var $slider = $("ul#bxslider");

        var slider = $slider.bxSlider({
            mode: 'vertical',
            slideMargin: 5,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true
        });

        //mousewheel events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up

        $slider.on("mousewheel", function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {

            //console.log(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);

            if (delta > 0) {
                slider.goToPrevSlide();
            }
            if (deltaY < 0){
                slider.goToNextSlide();
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        });



    });

})(window, jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
html, body.home, body.home #page, body.home .site-content, .content-area-home, main.site-main-home, body.home article, body.home .entry-content, .sabreSlider {
    height: 100%;
}

body.home .entry-content {
    margin: 0px;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
}

ul.bxslider {
    margin: 0px;
}

.bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100% !important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.bxslider, .bxslider li {
    height: 100% !important;;
}
.bxslider li {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    left: 0;
    border: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.bx-controls-direction {
    display: none;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px !important;
    top: 45%;
    right: 26px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item {
    display: block !important;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: transparent;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #f16625;
    border-color: #f16625;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance, snippets, refactoring, etc.

Comment: Did I post this in the wrong forum or something?  Nobody has stopped by with a comment or answer.  If I haven't included enough information, please let me know what else I can provide to help someone give me the guidance I need to resolve this.  I will happily add whatever I need to add.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your'e in the right forum, but you should create a demo on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). I'm very familiar with bxSlider, and like to help, but I (like many others) don't have a lot of time to create a demo from scratch. Tbh, I'm having a hard time visualizing your problem.

Comment: This can be closed out.  Design scrapped the footer on the homepage.  I would've notified this task, but I completely forgot, and on top of that, I never got your comment, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but i believe you need the attribute: "data-slide-index" on the slides. So that it can put them in a sortable order. I used a similar piece of code as your concept, and it worked exactly how you expected. And the differences I have in comparison are:

1. I used a custom pager
2. On those items used the 'data-slide-index'

I know this is question is old but hopefully can help somebody if they run across the issue in the future.